# Outlook CRM plugin not syncing cases properly

Tags: microsoft-outlook, dynamics-crm

We have CRM 2011 on premise.

One of our users sees more cases in the Active Cases view in Outlook than they do in the Active Cases view in Internet Explorer. The Active Cases view is unmodified from the default. This has been going on for a few weeks.

All his synchronisation settings look ok. There are no errors in the CRM eventlog on his machine.

How can I investigate?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu

Comment: @JamesWood So which site is it most suitable for?

Comment: Check what is the default view for the user in Outlook and in Internet Explorer. The affected user might have a different view set up as the default view. You can capture log level traces from the Diagnostics for CRM client for outlook, which can assist further.

Comment: Could it be some plugin on RetrieveMultiple message?

Answer (score 0):

You can investigate using Fiddler to intercept the network traffic & see the query being used to retrieve the case list. See if there's a difference between Web & Outlook.

I would start with any Plugin registered on RetrieveMultiple message on Incident entity, which might impact the resultset.